# base64.encodebytes fails to insert newline chars

Tags: python-3.x, base64

I must be missing something obvious. The function below successfully generates a base64 encoded string from an image file, but according to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.encodebytes), I expected it to have newlines every 76 characters.

```py
def generateBase64(filein):
    import base64
    with open(filein, 'rb') as f:
        return base64.encodebytes(f.read())
```

calling it on an image file  (.png) thus: `print(generateBase64(imgpath))` just returns one long string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since the object you're returning is bytes, try decoding it first like: `returned_base64_object.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: Hah! I was right: I was missing something obvious. Thanks so much @Sparrow1029 for pointing it out!